# How to classify the type of file creation using Notify?

Tags: macos, rust

I am trying to watch my desktop folder on Mac. Whenever I take a screenshot, I want to classify it as a file creation event. However, the Rust crate [notify-debouncer-mini](https://crates.io/crates/notify-debouncer-mini) always returns 'kind: Any' for all the events.

Am I doing something wrong?

code:

```
async fn watch_dir() {
    let desktop_path = desktop_dir();
    let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();
    let mut debouncer = new_debouncer(Duration::from_secs(1), tx).unwrap();
    let watcher = debouncer.watcher();
    watcher
        .watch(desktop_path.as_ref().unwrap(), RecursiveMode::Recursive)
        .unwrap();

    loop {
        match rx.recv() {
            Ok(event) => {
                println!("watch event: =====> {:?}", event); // Ok([DebouncedEvent { path: "../screenshot.png", kind: Any }])
            }
            Err(e) => {
                eprintln!("watch error: {:?}", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you try [notify](https://crates.io/crates/notify) ?

Comment: @devio Please elaborate **why**. There's many things they could do.

Comment: @kmdreko it worked, can you please post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notify-debouncer-mini is pretty simple and only debounces events based on timeframe regardless what kind the events were and thus loses that information.

You could use [notify](https://crates.io/crates/notify) directly without debouncing or use [notifiy-debouncer-full](https://crates.io/crates/notify-debouncer-full) which is much "smarter" about debouncing events. Both give you access to the original [`Event`](https://docs.rs/notify/6.1.1/notify/event/struct.Event.html) where the `kind` is much more descriptive.